# How to generate 2 different plots in one code?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

So I have two plots which I display in my Tkinter program by saving those plots in .png. The thing is, for some reason program displays 1st graph on the 2nd (you can see a little bit of line in a photo of the graph I get). [That's how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01N6B.png) and [that's what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AUvB.png).
My code:

```
# ## Graphs & Mood ## #
xpList = []
moodList = []


def makeGraph1():
    global graph1, column
    # Make a data frame
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': xpList, 'y1': moodList})
    # multiple line plot
    num = 0
    for column in df.drop('x', axis=1):
        num += 1
    plt.plot(df['x'], df[column], marker='', linewidth=1, alpha=0.9, label=column)
    plt.xlabel("xp", fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel("humor", fontsize=20)

    plt.savefig("images/graph1.png", bbox_inches="tight")
    graph1 = Image.open("images/graph1.png").resize((587 // 2, 432 // 2), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    graph1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(graph1)


makeGraph1()
gC1 = Label(root, image=graph1, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
gC1.place(x=875, y=440)


def dispGraph1():
    global gC1
    makeGraph1()
    gC1.destroy()
    gC1 = Label(root, image=graph1, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
    gC1.place(x=875, y=440)


def numB(num):
    xpList.append(xp)
    moodList.append(num)
    if len(moodList) > 1:
        moodList[-1] += moodList[-2]
    dispGraph1()
    print(moodList)


def makeGraph2():
    global graph2
    # make the pie circular by setting the aspect ratio to 1
    plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
    values = [3, 12, 5, 8]
    labels = ["Math", "Banana", "Praying to Shrek", "Sitting"]

    def make_autopct(values):
        def my_autopct(pct):
            total = sum(values)
            val = int(round(pct * total / 100.0))
            return '{p:.2f}% ({v:d} minut)'.format(p=pct, v=val)

        return my_autopct

    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 6.8})
    plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct=make_autopct(values))

    plt.savefig("images/graph2.png", bbox_inches="tight")
    graph2 = Image.open("images/graph2.png").resize((587 // 2, 432 // 2), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    graph2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(graph2)


makeGraph2()
gC2 = Label(root, image=graph2, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
gC2.place(x=875, y=140)


def dispGraph2():
    global gC2
    makeGraph2()
    gC2.destroy()
    gC2 = Label(root, image=graph2, borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
    gC2.place(x=875, y=140)
```

I was thinking, that maybe my program can't tell the difference between them because I import matplotlib as plt so I tried doing something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt2
```

but it still does the same. Also, one more thing - graphs aren't premade but are updated every time when the user updates data.

Comment: That attempted solution with import made me giggle.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That was the only thing that came to my mind so I tried, even though it is stupid

Comment: Too much going on in your code - I suggest you boil it down to a simpler code for your question. All this pandas stuff, storing things here and there seems unrelated to your problem. And can't you create in tkinter a [figure with two subplots](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) and provide each function with the `ax` argument, so they know where to plot? I don't know tkinter, so no idea if that can work.